# SQL collate using select query on multiple fields

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa, spring-data-jpa, collate

I have an a spring boot project with a nativeQuery sql query that is executed by front end code each time a user types in a letter in a certain field. In the query, user input serves as a parameter to two database fields. I currently have it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID LIKE '%input%' OR NAME LIKE '%input%' collate binary_ci ORDER BY NAME ASC
```

I am testing it in postman, and results seem to indicate the collation above applies to both fields, but I want to make sure it applies to both fields. I've searched but did not find posts or documentation that answers my question.

Does the way I have it suffice, or do I need it after each field name like below?

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE ID LIKE '%input%' collate binary_ci OR NAME LIKE '%input%' collate binary_ci ORDER BY NAME ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The COLLATE operator determines the collation for an expression
>
> Source: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COLLATE-Operator.html#GUID-1B8CE3B0-77FC-455C-8400-6F81CF188D7B

That means that you have to apply it per column expression in your case